# Laravel phpunit testing mail sending

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, phpunit

Im trying to test mail sending in laravel 5.1 application. 
    I need run tests on prod server.
    I need MAIL_DRIVER=log at app environment for running test.
    And MAIL_DRIVER=smtp for production in my .env file.
    I edited phpunit.xml at application root folder and added line:

```
<env name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="log"/>

<php>
     <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
     <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
     <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
     <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
     <env name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="log"/>
</php>
```

The problem is when I running test it still use MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Where have you mentioned smtp?

Comment: I set in  my  .env file

Answer (score 0):

Try to redefine mail transport type directly. Changing environment constants will do nothing (or share the code where MAIL_DRIVER is used).

Comment: I use source code from laracast and shared on github https://gist.github.com/JeffreyWay/b501c53d958b07b8a332

Comment: Create a mock for SwiftMailer class and override `send`-function

Comment: Actually I need mails keep sending, but  to log... I cant find why mailer proceed using smtp. I tried to change config/mail.php and hardcoded driver key to 'log', then removed MAIL_DRIVER option from .env file, but application proceed use smtp. The only way I can change it is fixing .env file. Now as I can see edition phpunit.xml has no sense......

Comment: Is it possible to force application use another .env file for testing ?

Comment: Absolutely, it's a part of best practices (for DEV/LIVE/TEST different configurations). It can be a part of one file, or multiples. Choose is done by setevn in vhost (in your case: `<env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>`).

Comment: When I check IOC it uses 'log' option, read it from phpunit.xml. But SwiftMailer ignore it.

Comment: You wrote about setting environment using <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/> And Im talking about using another .env file ... When I run app()->environmentFile() it returns '.env', even I run app()->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.testing'). SwiftMailer proceed use smtp, but in .env.testing placed 'log'

Comment: Could you share in your question a part of code where MAIL_DRIVER is in use?

Comment: I only edit it in .env and phpunit.xml files snd didnot use in my app and tests files.  As I understand IOC includes application configuration and getting it from .env file.